# Want to add custom post type for facebook feed

Tags: php, custom-post-types, custom-field

I have Facebook api for feeds. I want to add multiple user's Facebook feeds on their page. So, how can I add custom post type for Facebook feeds, which users can login to their account to get feeds from their user dashboard!?

Comment: is facebook api for feeds a plugin? Can you rephrase your question to use more than 2 sentences? The last sentence is difficult to understand and could mean lots of things. Use the Edit link underneath the question tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the post via function call wp_insert_post. where you need to pass the parameter of post type as name of your custom post type.

```
$wordpress_post = array(
'post_title' => 'Post title',
'post_content' => 'Post Content',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'post_author' => 1,
'post_type' => 'custom_post_type'
);
 
wp_insert_post( $wordpress_post );
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the question, can you explain what `wp_insert_post` does to solve the OP's problem?

Comment: He wanted to fetch the feed and save it as custom post type. For that I recommended to use the function wp_insert_post() let me know isnt this correct approach ?